# How to insert into a table after doing a select in a form

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-insert

I have a PHP form that is collecting information and writing it to a database and it is working correctly. I have one field that is a select to choose entries from an existing table. I would like that result to be inserted into a different table but can't get the insert into to work. I would like to insert the FacilityName field chosen in the select to table2.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facility");

print "<select name=\"Id\" > \n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $Id = $row['Id'];
    $FacilityName = $row['FacilityName'];
    print "<option value=$Id>$FacilityName\n";
```

Comment: for future reference: don't put lines of code in backticks, look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and then use its syntax for putting code in your question.

Comment: So, you need an INSERT, right?

Comment: for your question: what have you tried? I don't see any code where you try to INSERT the data you fetch back into something called `table2`?

Comment: I had an error on my page until I did the crtl-k, will try it a different way. I have tried several different insert, I don't get any error's, it just is not written to DB.

Comment: $sql= "INSERT INTO preceptor ('FacilityName')VALUES(\"$result\")";

Comment: $_SQL="INSERT INTO preceptor (FacilityName) VALUES ('FacilityName'); 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'userid';";